# AttributeError: module 'pyautogui' has no attribute 'locateCentreOnScreen'

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror, pyautogui

I have `PyAutoGUI-0.9.52` and there **no file** in the working directory named pyautogui. I have `pillow` installed, but still, it shows this error please can someone help me.

This is the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\lolllll.py", line 4, in <module>
    pyautogui.click(pyautogui.locateCentreOnScreen('launcher.png'))
AttributeError: module 'pyautogui' has no attribute 'locateCentreOnScreen'
```

If there is no solution please suggest a different module which can do this. But I would prefer to *stick with this*.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow and congrats on your first question! Make sure to read the guideline on how to post questions. As a rule, one shares the code that generated the error message. That is because it helps us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

We can't help you without code. However, a simple google search results in the fact that you mistyped, and the function is `pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(...)`, with a properly spelled `center`.